# Right strategy for checks made in @AfterTest method

Tags: java, multithreading, testing, automated-tests, appium

I'm not sure if this is a suitable title for the problem. Please suggest.

We have end-to-end payments tests being run in several threads. (It is a mobile testing: Java, Appium, and TestNg) There are many countries and for each of them different payment methods need to be test.

Each test consists of:

- logging in under a specific email address associated with a specific payment method and country
- adding products to cart
- choosing payment method
- proceeding to payment and payment itself

Afterwards a page with total amount and order number info appears.
Then we go to inbox and compare the data from the page with the data in the email.

Delay to get email is about 30-60 sec. So each test need to wait for such amount of time. That doesn't make us happy.

So the idea is to collect all info (email-orderNumber-totalInfo) somewhere and check data match after all tests passed. As there are several threads being run so we come up with next ideas:

1.Adding specific ThreadContext for each thread in @BeforeTest method and then at the end of each test (when total info appears) save data to file name as ThreadContext.json
And then in @AfterTest method read data and check all emails at once per each thread.
But we faced with a problem that we need to keep json valid we need firstly read file then add new JsonObject and save altogether. Problem was with reading/writing to files. Sometimes exceptions occurred so some checks skipped.

2. Then we try to save it to csv files. But again exceptions appeared from time to time.
3. Now there is an idea to use ThreadLocals for keeping data and then use at the end. But I am not sure for stability and performance.

Could you please give your point of view which solution would be the best?

Comment: I would caution against putting asserts in an `@AfterTest`.  Asserts are part of the test, `@AfterTest` is really for teardown.  To the main point: once the test has completed, it's passed.  You can't fail a test after the fact.  It will always be harder to understand what's failed, and you'll end up fighting the framework.  Instead see if you can't use a harness to capture the email (dumbster?  mockmock? mailtrap?) to remove the delay.  Don't violate the fundamental definition of a test.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But this is black box testing. I can't simulate mailing.

Comment: So mailtrap is an external service that acts like an smtp service to your app. so only difference would be your smtp config as compared to prod.  If you can't do that, I'd still strongly recommend avoiding asserts in an `@AfterTest`, better to have long running tests and see if you can't just run them in parallel to speed up your overall test run.

Comment: "Delay to get email is about 30-60 sec. So each test need to wait for such amount of time. That doesn't make us happy." Which part makes you unhappy? It sounded like the delay was making you unhappy, but from your comment, it seems the problem is that all those delays accumulate. To avoid that, I would configure the tests to run in parallel.

Comment: @BluE Please check the problem statement. It is said that: "We have end-to-end payments tests being run in several threads."

Comment: Each thread runs about 15-20 tests.

Comment: @Berol: Can you please explain your problem? To me, it seems this question, tries to solve it in a very specific way that doesn't work well with the framework. Also, it might not even solve the problem: The email delay will still be there as long as you are doing black box tests. Maybe there are other solutions for the underlying problem?

Comment: Like if each thread just runs one test, would you still have a problem?